# What is the meaning of the 'connection' Ansible directive?

Tags: ansible

```
---
  - name: Upgrade Device
    hosts: all
    gather_facts: no
    connection: local
```

As far as I know, an Ansible Playbook is always executed by the managed hosts where the connection link between them and the control nodes is through SSH.
What does the 'connection' directive do exactly ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is to execute the tasks locally on the same host (i.e., the controller) where the playbook is run.

From the [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html#local-playbooks),

> It may be useful to use a playbook locally, rather than by connecting over SSH.

Comment: you omitted the most confusing part of that line in the docs: "It may be useful to use a playbook locally *on a remote host*, rather than by connecting over SSH."

Comment: The documentation seems to be re-worded recently. But what is the confusion in that sentence

Comment: what does that mean...locally, on a remote... My understanding is that the local connection means everything runs on the controller.  A remote host is only local if you're on it, and to get there, you need ssh, in non technical terms.

Comment: Once you have logged in to a remote host, that host logically becomes a local host

Comment: Do you have any ideas re. a simple playbook we can write, and include here, to prove/demonstrate this?  I'm still skeptical, mainly to due to vagueness of the language.